# TCP SYN flooding from Linux Machine(which is acting as client) to Destination (Server)

Tags: networking, tcp, linux-kernel, tcpclient

ROB(CLIENT) and BOB(SERVER) is Established with TCP , after some time ROB Linux Machine frequently sending TCP [SYN] to BOB(SERVER). The SYN packet is initiated automatically , which is not triggered by any service from ROB. Due to this BOB is dropping TCP connection .

We have enabled TCP Dump in ROB machine and Identified this issue.

How to Identify who is sending the Unnecessary SYN initiation from ROB to BOB ?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the `auditctl` kernel level auditing framework that has been built into Linux for a while.  It won't be pretty, but it will create audit records that you can then work through and tie to users.  For example:

```
 sudo auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S socket -F success=1
```

Once that is done (you may need to install auditctl if it isn't there already... Check your package manager...), you can review the audit logs using `ausearch`

```
 sudo ausearch -sc connect
```

The records will include the PID, PPID, and UID.  You can dig further, but decoding the arguments to the call will take some effort since they are just raw hunks of data and will not be represented as the structures that they actually are.

Also, note that depending on your Linux version, you may find that you need to monitor a different system call.  Obviously, the `-b64` needs to match your architecture as well.